# NancyFx vs WCF REST API

Tags: wcf, rest, nancy

I'm currently migrate functionality from WCF REST to Nancy. I'm hosting Nancy in WCF host. But I would like to better understand what freatures, if any, I miss from migrating WCF REST API to Nancy.

I tried to create small web service within WCF REST and SPA. It was very inconvenient in terms of session managment and authentication. So I decided to use NancyFx. For now it seems everything ok.

It is a little bit hard to formulate a general question, but I want to undestrand what are implications of using NancyFx instead of WCF REST api for self-host? Performace issues? I've mentioned that on VS 2010 it is a little bit slow to debug NancyFx rest api...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe this question is better suited for programmers.stackexchange. Having said that I think Nancy shines because of it's high level of testability, the simple and terse application code it lets you write and it's high level of flexibility (because of e.g. it's modularity).